# Error on calling a stored procedure from java - Invalid JDBC data type -10

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a java class from which i am connecting to the SQL Server 2008 which is on a remote machine.I Can retrieve data using a class which means the connection is working fine.
But when i try to run a stored procedure it gives me

> Exception as com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException - Invalid JDBC data type -10.

Find the code below. Can anyone help me with this? I have added the `sqljdbc`, `sqljdbc4` jars to my class buildpath.

```
CallableStatement cs=null;
con = SqlConnectionManager.getConnection();
cs = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.PKG_ER_SEL.sp_ERGetJobCode(?,?,?)}");
cs.setInt(1, orgId);//v_org
cs.setString(2, compCode);//v_type
cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR); //getting exception here
cs.executeUpdate(); 
ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(3);
if (resultSet != null) {
    while ( resultSet.next() ) {
    JobVO  obj = new JobVO();
                                  obj.setCode(resultSet.getString("CODE"));
                             obj.setName(resultSet.getString("NAME"));
     seqAttList.add(obj);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
SqlConnectionManager.releaseConnection(con);
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using `cs.getObject(java.sql.Types.XXXXX)`. [See here for what datatype java.sql.Types](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefjdbc20377.html)

Comment: I changed the line to ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(java.sql.Types.INTEGER); --But i get same error

Comment: `cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR); ` here to use `java.sql.Types.XXXXX` use appropriate type as you are having in you DB as in mapping link I dont see anything like `CURSOR` but [here I see CURSOR is -10](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/constant-values.html#oracle_jdbc_OracleTypes_CURSOR)

Comment: @Smit I didnot quite understand, could you please explain like what exactly should it be/??

Comment: See you `registerOutParamaeter` is of type `OracleTypes.CURSOR` and it has designated values as `-10` (See at links I gave you in my comments)  and you are calling  `cs.getObject(3)` where I think its getting conflicting. If you use same values you will get succeed. But as you have Integer data type and why dont you directly call `cs.getInt()`

Comment: @Smit - Its not integer datatype, its cursor. As i mentioned the output parameter of the procedure is CURSOR.You have the program, where exactly you want me to change?

Comment: can anyone help on this. Like in Oracle we can call the CURSOR , how can i call it for a SQL Server??

Comment: I can't say I know Oracle, but returning a CURSOR as an OUTPUT parameter from a stored procedure? Even if it were possible, I can't come up with any situation where that would be a good idea.

Comment: -1 ... sql-server tagged post, and you're using OracleTypes?

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA get the ResultSet from the call to `executeQuery` on the `Statement` object. The ResultSet instance is the equivalent of a CURSOR in T-SQL. Read some more about using ResultSet [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

For SQL Server you call/execute a stored procedure as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx). A simple example would be `EXECUTE my_stored_procedure` if your stored procedure is called `my_stored_procedure`.